# How to link Android Application to MongoDB for bidirectional communication

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, api, digital-ocean

Currently, I am at a design halt for a mobile application I am working on. The issue I am having is determining the best route in connecting my mobile application with a database.

I am using a digital ocean server to host my content. At this point, I am using mongoDB to store my data. The app has to allow users to upload media to mongoDB. Additionally, the app has to be able to retrieve media from mongoDB and display the media in the app.

Through research, I have learned that connecting the app directly to mongoDB is bad practice (for obvious reasons). The alternative approach I have learned, is to make your own API to handle the requests. This is where I am really at a stand still.

I plan on using node.js to write my API(which I am still really trying to get a grasp on). What I do not understand is how this API and the java code for the Android app interact. How am I to post data from the android app through an API to my database? Conversely, how am I to get data from my database through an API to my app?

Any help, suggestions, recommended reading, etc. in this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: Basically you are asking for a tutorial or a book, that's not a good question for SO:SE (see [ask]. Anyway, what about the [cloud provider's tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/mongodb?type=tutorials)?

Comment: I have been over a decent amount of them, along with YouTube tutorials and seminars. Everything I have watched/read tends towards web application design. I can understand where you would think I am asking for a tutorial.  I'm not. I'm just looking for understanding or a nudge in the right direction from someone who has been there.

Comment: I may not understand correctly your question since I thought the answer to what you are looking for were here: [How To Connect Node.js to a MongoDB Database on a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-node-js-to-a-mongodb-database-on-a-vps).

Comment: That link does provide good support for connecting node.js to mongoDB. For me, its the link between all three that is throwing me-- all three being Android (Java), Mongo, and Node; rather, how all three work together in order to provide the dynamic content. I don't understand piggy-backing of the rest API, lets say (myserver.js) in order to provide content to the Android app.